# how to set data attribute for default route in nest js

Tags: node.js, nestjs, router

I need to set the data attributes for all routers in my application.

**Ex:- http://localhost:8080/tenantId/category**

**tenantId = store-0154**

I send tenantId from my FE for every request.

In My code, I need to use query param or something. But the problem is I have to write query param for tenantId for each router I create.

There is a way to create a global route for my situation.
That means my global route is  **http://localhost:8080/tenantId/**.

Thank you.